# Retrieve uploaded relativePath file on server side

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jquery-file-upload

I'm using fileUpload from Primefaces (JSF framework) based on jQuery-File-Upload. I'm trying to make this component supporting drag&drop folder thanks to new File API of Firefox or Chrome. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory#Example So far, I've been able to make it happen thanks to passthrough attribute.

One of the interesting feature is "webkitRelativePath" allowing to know the relative path of an uploaded file.

I'm wondering how I could retrieve this info on server side, so I can create an object with this new info.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have it client side, you can always try to send it to the server by 'attaching' it to the ajax call as a param. Not sure if that works, but it is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just read his from fileupload.js:

```
_initXHRData: function (options) {
     ...
     formData.append(
     ($.type(options.paramName) === 'array' &&
          options.paramName[index]) || paramName,
          file,
          file.uploadName || file.name
     );
     ...
}
```

(file containing webKitRelativePath)

So I guess the info is already pass to the server, don't you think? Since i'm using Servlet 3.0, I should be able to retrieve it from `Part` object, finger crossed...

Comment: I used a trick, instead of `file.uploadName || file.name` I wrote this `file.webkitRelativePath || file.name` since uploadName does not seem to be valid property while webkitRelativePath "is" (not standard feature)

Comment: Another trick would be to add a new param to FormData, and make the key suffixed by "-webkitRelativePath", then server side, you have a try if the key exists

Comment: there is a doc talking about this actually https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data, but it does not look that straightforward to bring this in JSF